# unix concatenate list of files into on line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, ls

In a directory, there is several files such as:

```
file1 
file2 
file3
```

Is there a simple way to concatenate those files to get one line (connected by "OR") in bash as follows:

`file1 OR file2 OR file3`

Or do I need to write a script for it?

Comment: What did you try and fail? Post it even if it was trivial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do that with

```
printf '%s OR ' $(ls -1 *) | sed 's/OR $/''/'; echo -e '\n'
```

Where `ls -1 *` is the directory.

Comment: You should avoid file names with spaces on Linux, but you're right. I assumed the OP file names are without spaces

Comment: Please go through this: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @Vinny is filename `OR` should be avoided too?

Comment: @Kent It would be confusing, but that's what the OP asked for - 'OR' between filenames

Comment: The `printf` produces output that has no terminating newline and so is not a valid POSIX text line (or file) so YMMV with what any tool you pipe it too might do with it as that's undefined behavior. You should add the newline before the pipe and you can just use `*` instead of `$(ls -1)` to get ride of many of the other issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function to print all filenames (including ones with space, newline or special characters) with `" OR "` as separator (*assuming your filename doesn't contain ASCII code `4`*):

```
orfiles() {
   local IFS=$'\4'
   local out="$*"
   echo "${out//$'\4'/ OR }"
}
```

Then call it as:

```
orfiles *
```

**How it works:**

1. We set `IFS` (Internal Field Separator) to ASCII `4` locally inside the function
2. We store output of `"$*"` in local variable `out`. This will place `\4` after each filename in variable `$out`.
3. Finally using BASH string substitution we globally replace `\4` by `" OR "` while printing the output from `$out`.

In Unix systems `IFS` is only a single character delimiter therefore it cannot store multi character string `" OR "` and we have to do this in 2 steps as shown above.

Comment: `++`, best answer! would be wise to say, why `IFS` was set and replaced that way. Reason being `bash` does not allow multi-character `IFS` like `Awk` or other tools do

Comment: Why use `\4` instead of NUL `\0`?

Comment: I tried using `IFS=$'\0'` but `out` variable didn't have any `\0`

Comment: Ah, probably because bash uses C-style strings which are NUL-delimited and so NULs can't appear within strings and `$*` is a string. OK, good to know, thx.

Answer (score 1):

The moment that should be considered is that a filename could contain whitespace(s).
Use the following **ls** + **awk** solution:

```
ls -1 * | awk '{ r=(r)? r" OR "$0 : $0 }END{ print r }'
```

---

Workaround for filenames with newline(s):

```
echo -e $(ls -1b hello* | awk -v RS= '{gsub(/\n/," OR ",$0); gsub(/\\ /," ",$0); print $0}')
```

- `-b` - *ls* option to print C-style escapes for nongraphic characters

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: @Kent, you did not get it. I didn't say that I will handle spaces - I said that it's an important moment. That's why `ls -1` had been used

Comment: @anubhava, have you tested filenames like `hello\name`? Also, read my comment for Kent

Comment: Yes I did and this `awk` printed output in 2 lines. Use this: `date > $'hello\name'; ls -1 hello* | awk '{ r=(r)? r" OR "$0 : $0 }END{ print r }'` and see what I mean.

Comment: `hello\name` doesn't have literal new line character. Create a file as `touch $'hello\nthere'` and then run your command.

Comment: @anubhava, ok, I've added a workaround. It gives the same output as your `orfiles` function

Comment: `echo -e` is not portable. You can use: `ls -1 --quoting-style=c hello* | awk -v RS= '{gsub(/"\n/, " OR \"")} 1' | xargs printf '%b\n'`

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1|awk -v q='"' '{printf "%s%s", NR==1?"":" OR ", q $0 q}END{print ""}'
```

the ls & awk way to do it, with example that the filename containing spaces:

```
kent$  ls -1
file1
file2
'file with OR and space'

kent$  ls -1|awk -v q='"' '{printf "%s%s", NR==1?"":" OR ", q $0 q}END{print ""}'
"file1" OR "file2" OR "file with OR and space"
```

Comment: If you are parsing the output of ls, -Q will put the file names in quotes and so ls -1Q will give "file1" "file2"

Answer (score 0):

```
$ for f in *; do printf '%s%s' "$s" "$f"; s=" OR "; done; printf '\n'
file1 OR file2 OR file3
```